WebDriverException timed out after 60 seconds when open a folder dialog
I'm currently working on automating an electron application using Selenium Webdriver in C#. I'm using H.InputSimulator library to simulate keyboard actions and handle windows folder dialog in order to select a folder so the application can read in files and display it.
Below is the current code I have that works. When the test clicks on the button to open the file dialog, the dialog will open. The test will hang for 60 seconds and then throws a WebDriverException which gets caught. Afterwards the test will proceed to entering the folder path and selecting it.
public void ClickAndInputFolderPath(string path)
{
    try
    {
       BrowseFolderButton.Click(); 
    }
    catch (WebDriverException e)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(e);
    }

    var inputSimulator = new InputSimulator();
    inputSimulator.Keyboard.TextEntry(path);
    inputSimulator.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.TAB);
    inputSimulator.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);
}

From what I understand the IWebdriver performs the Click() method and it waits for the document.readyState to return. I guess with opening a dialog this does not happen?
I'm trying to figure out if there's a better way to either avoid this WebDriverException as it hangs the test for 60 seconds before it continues or reduce the wait before it throws the WebDriverException.
driver.Manage.Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("pathToButton")).Click()

I'm not sure if I'm even on the right track?

it has to try to wait to see if a navigation occurs. (usually it knows that pretty quickly and this isn't a problem... this is probably electron specific)  The only way to modify that is to set the pageLoadStrategy.  (you can set it to "none" which would never wait, but this is global and would affect strategy for entire test.  If your electron app never navigates, though, this might be a good solution... otherwise, if set to "none", you need to make sure to always use webdriverwaits with explicit conditions that would be true only after navigation)

The W3C WebDriver spec mentions: "It is not always clear how long this will cause the algorithm to wait, and it is acknowledged that some implementations may have unavoidable race conditions.": https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#element-click

it may be that pageLoadStrategy won't help at all here.  It may be waiting on the browser thread to see if navigation will occur.  Possible workarounds would be to execute script to generate the click, or dispatch an Action.

Thanks. I think what I will do is to attempt the page load strategy first that's set to none. If that doesn't work out then I will try to execute a script to click and see if that can be work around.

I have tried to execute javascript click action. However once the dialog opens it still hangs and times out in 60 seconds.

The only way that I tried so far that isn't giving me the 60 seconds time out WebDriverException is when I use javascript executor to perform the click and set the PageLoadStrategy to "None" and I'm debugging and stepping through the methods. It will give me a script time out instead which doesn't take that long to throw. If I run the test normally it will fail so might not be feasible

if using the JS executor I don't think you'd need to change PageLoadStrategy.  Was that part really necessary?
